# get element array from input text in angular scope

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I use charjs in angular. I will create chart from dinamic data.
How make array in `$scope.fruits.datas` from value input text `persen` ?

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="persen" id="textinput2" readonly style="font-size: 20px;text-align:center; color:aliceblue; background:#60222A; " />
```

JS

```
function calcscore(){
 var score = 0;
 var persen=0;
 $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
     score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    persen=((score/17)*100).toFixed(2);     
 });

 $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
 $("input[name=persen]").val(persen)}

});
```

ANGULAR

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
$scope.fruits = {
    labels: ["a", "b"],
    datas : [9,3],
    color: ["#FEBD01","#FF8C00"],

};
```

Comment: explain what your problem precisely.

Comment: array element "datas" is derived from the value obtained by the input text name="persen". while the input text value comes from the score obtained. How make array in $scope.fruits.datas from value input text persen ?...thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your problem, you need to Assign **persen** values to **$scope.fruits.datas**

for That 
Define persen as $scope.persen=[]

JS

```
$scope.persen=[];


 calcscore(){
         var score = 0;

         $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
             score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
            $scope.persen.push(((score/17)*100).toFixed(2));     
         });

         $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
         $("input[name=persen]").val(persen)}

        });
```

Angular

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
$scope.fruits = {
    labels: ["a", "b"],
    datas : $scope.persen,
    color: ["#FEBD01","#FF8C00"],

};
```